# Haxe/Nodejs debugging - Source mapping

Tags: node.js, haxe

How to enable source mapping on nodejs? I wish to have the stack trace to map on the .hx files instead of the generated .js file.

Main.hx:

```
package;

class Main
{
    public static function main()
        throw "test";
}
```

build.hxml:

```
-lib hxnodejs
-cp src
-js bin/index.js
-main Main
```

output: (`cd bin && node index.js`)

```
/Users/kevin/Codes/testnodejs/bin/index.js:10
    throw new js__$Boot_HaxeError("test");
    ^
Error: test
    at Function.Main.main (/Users/kevin/Codes/testnodejs/bin/index.js:10:8)
    at console.undefined.log (/Users/kevin/Codes/testnodejs/bin/index.js:21:6)
    at Object. (/Users/kevin/Codes/testnodejs/bin/index.js:22:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install "source-map-support" from npm

   ```
   npm install source-map-support
   ```
2. Enable `-debug` in your hxml (so that Haxe generates the source map file)
3. Run `install()` in the very beginning of your program:

   ```
   js.Lib.require('source-map-support').install();
   ```
4. Assign the wrapCallSite function to haxe.CallStack

   ```
   haxe.CallStack.wrapCallSite = js.Lib.require('source-map-support').wrapCallSite;
   ```